# Unable to fetch the JSON array values using jq in shell script

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I'm trying to get the Key from the below JSON file:

I just executed the below command which will give the below JSON output

**Command:**

```
jq -r '.issues'
```

**Output:**

```
"issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "1999875",
      "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/1999875",
      "key": "KINDLEAMZ-67578"
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "2019428",
      "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/2019428",
      "key": "KINDLEAMZ-68661"
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "2010958",
      "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/2010958",
      "key": "KINDLEAMZ-68167"
    }
  ]
}
```

I just want to get the output as below format and not sure how to get it.

**Expected Output:**

```
{
"JIRA-1":"KINDLEAMZ-67578",

"JIRA-2":"KINDLEAMZ-68661",

"JIRA-3":"KINDLEAMZ-68167"
}
```

How can I get key value from each of the array and display like above? and JIRA-n will be increase based on the result.

Comment: for your consideration, here's also an _alternative_ (i.e. non-jq) solution for the JSON manipulation in your question, based on a unix `walk-path` utility jtc: `<file.json jtc -w'[issues][:]<Idx>k<Idx>I1[key]' -T'{"JIRA-{Idx}": {{}}}' -jjll`. Let me know If you're interested - I can elaborate on the tool usage in a separate answer. (PS. I'm a developer of the tool)

Comment: actually neither my above solution, nor the provided one facilitate your requirement: _"JIRA-n will be increase based on the result"_. Because if you insert a record in a middle which does not carry `key` label, then both deliver incorrect result. My solution could be fixed (and simplified if the label `key` is unique within your JSON) like this: `<file.json jtc -w'<key>l:<Idx>I1'  -T'{"JIRA-{Idx}": {{}}}' -jjll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array, you can use `to_entries/1` to map the array an array of index and values. You could then map out to the keys and values you want on the object either using `reduce` or `with_entries/1`.

```
reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({};
    .["JIRA-\($key + 1)"] = $value.key
)
```

https://jqplay.org/s/y6AFKg2dSM

```
.issues | with_entries({key: "JIRA-\(.key + 1)", value: .value.key})
```

https://jqplay.org/s/H2uxyFJn9E

---

It seems like you're using a version lesser than 1.5. You'll need to make some adjustments and remove the deconstruction.

```
reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as $e ({};
    .["JIRA-\($e.key + 1)"] = $e.value.key
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try and accept your answer. It really helps a lot.

Comment: Jeff Mercado - I tried to run the same command in shell and getting below error  error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '$' reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .["JIRA-($key + 1)"] = $value.key ) ^ 1 compile error   can you please help me on this? I tried but i'm not able to identify what went to wrong. I'm using jq version 1.5

Comment: Can you verify that you're on 1.5? It should work there as written, it's failing on the deconstruction part `{$key,$value}` which was added in 1.5. What is the output of `jq --version`? It can be rewritten to work with 1.4 however and leave out the deconstruction. `reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as $e ({}; .["JIRA-\($e.key + 1)"] = $e.value.key)`

Comment: jq --version  Output: 1.5v

Comment: Jeff Mercado - Many kudo to you... Finally it worked with your magic spell... Once again thank you...

Comment: Pls post your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103344/syntax-error-observed-while-trying-to-parse-the-json-data-by-using-jq-shell-scri?noredirect=1#comment102600202_58103344