# Syntax error observed while trying to parse the JSON data by using jq shell script

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I have the the below input and I'm trying to fetch the Key details and trying to form a below json file but when I tried to run the below command it returned syntax error and I'm not sure How can I resolve this

Input (Response.Json):

```
{
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 4,
    "issues": [{
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "1999875",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/1999875",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-67578"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "2019428",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/2019428",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-68661"
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "2010958",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/2010958",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-68167"
        }
    ]
}
```

Command:

```
> getResponse=$( jq 'reduce (.issues | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value}
> ({}; .["JIRA-\($key + 1)"] = $value.key )' response.json );
```

Error:

> error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '$' reduce (.issues |
>   to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .["JIRA-($key + 1)"] = $value.key
>   ) ^ 1 compile error

**Expected Output:**

```
{
"JIRA-1":"KINDLEAMZ-67578",

"JIRA-2":"KINDLEAMZ-68661",

"JIRA-3":"KINDLEAMZ-68167"
}
```

Anyone please help me resolve this. I'm completely blocked and clueless...

Answer (score 0):

I've verified that the following works with your JSON sample;

```
.issues | reduce to_entries[] as $kv ({}; .["JIRA-\($kv.key)"] = $kv.value.key )
```

Comment: I'm using jq version 1.5 I don't think so its older one. I didn't get answer and the answer which you mentioned that didn't work on shell.